# Behavior of a JavaScript switch statement with the .attr() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, case

I have a JavaScript switch statement to identify if my img src equals some link, but when I run it, none of the case statements are executed. The line of execution falls right through.

```
switch (sitem.attr("src")) {
    case "../Stranice/Ultraga/Ultraga.html":
        $(".rectangle-u h2").text('ULTRAGA');
        $(".rectangle-d h2").text('NEZIR KAMENICA');
        break;
    case "../Stranice/Aida i Ajna/pocetna/pocetna.html":
        $(".rectangle-u h2").text('WEBSTRANICA');
        $(".rectangle-d h2").text('AIDA I AJNA');
        break;
    case "../Stranice/Vedad/Home/Home.html":
        $(".rectangle-u h2").text('GAME DRAGON');
        $(".rectangle-d h2").text('VEDAD FAZLIĆ');
        break;
}
```

How do I figure out why no case statements are being executed?

Comment: Simple debugging should show you why. `console.log(sitem.attr("src"));` Is it what you expect?

Comment: might want to add a default to that switch as well XD

Answer (score 2):

The `attr()` returns an absolute URL, which is why it's not matching your relative URLs.

Comment: can you post the fixed code, how it should look like

Comment: The fixed code is you using abslolute URLs in your switch statement. I can't provide those because I don't know them

Answer (score 0):

How about using a for each and check with if contains

```
   $(".Containerclass img").each(function() {  
      imgsrc = this.src;
      if (imgsrc.toLowerCase().indexOf("Ultraga.html") >= 0))
        {
          $(".rectangle-u h2").text('ULTRAGA');
          $(".rectangle-d h2").text('NEZIR KAMENICA');
        }
      else if (imgsrc.toLowerCase().indexOf("pocetna.html") >= 0))
        {
          $(".rectangle-u h2").text('WEBSTRANICA');
          $(".rectangle-d h2").text('AIDA I AJNA');
        }
      else if (imgsrc.indexOf("Home.html") >= 0))
        {
          $(".rectangle-u h2").text('GAME DRAGON');
          $(".rectangle-d h2").text('VEDAD FAZLIĆ');
        }
     });
```

Make sure if .toLowerCase() is used then the text inside indexOf()  must be in small letters.

All the best